# How to crop an image such that if coordinates don't exist, the other side is extended, hence keeping the size of the crop the same?

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I'm currently cropping images this way:

```
self.crop = self.img[self.y_center - self.radius:self.y_center + self.radius,
                        self.x_center - self.radius:self.x_center + self.radius:, ]
```

Where y_center and x_center are defined by clicks, and radius is the size of the crop. But I repeatedly run into a problem where the click is on an extreme side of an image. In that case, how do I extend the side on the other side of the image?

Basically I do not want to compromise the size.

Comment: Well, check if the rectangle around the point goes beyond the image, then move it the corresponding amount of pixels if it does, duh! Simple & stupid (c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple & stupid (r) way:

- check if the rectangle around the point goes beyond the image
- move it the corresponding amount of pixels if it does
- repeat for all the 4 sides

Not so s&s is how to handle the case where the rectangle is larger than the entire image, but we'll see...

```
# X,Y - size of the image - 1 (maximum possible values for x,y)
# x,y - click coordinates relative to the image
t=x+radius; if t>X: x-=t-X
t=y+radius; if t>Y: y-=t-Y
t=x-radius; if t<0: x-=t #t<0 so it's increased actually
t=y-radius; if t<0: y-=t
del t
crop = img[x-radius:min(x+radius,X), y-radius:min(y+radius,Y)]
```

With `min`, we handle the case when the rectangle is larger than the image.
We check from the "high" side because we chose the order of adjustments so that the last ones have docked the rectangle to the "low" side.